# Yom Kippur Segulah Question

Tags: sources-mekorot, money, yom-kippur, segulah, ark-aron-kodesh

Does anyone know of a Source  for Pesicha for Neilah being a segulah for Parnassah? Its something I have heard said is there a source anyone can send me to it would be appreciated?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, 0519275345. Remember you can edit your profile and make your username a bit more "personal" than a string of random numbers. :)

Comment: "Well know things don't need sources". Ask any CFO of a shul, Pesicha is a great source of income. :-)

Comment: In some places there are multiple Pesichos (?) for Neilah

Comment: @Danny That reminds me of the old line: 'Saying ketores from a klaf is a segula for parnassa. For the sofrim.'